# mariadb/mysql: How do I convert/UNPACK part of a BLOB to integer or double etc

Tags: mariadb, blob, unpack

I use a mariaDB/mysql database to "reverse engineer" the structure of binary data.
A column called "data" contains lets say 152 byte long binary "blobs".

Within another columns I have listed what kind of information I expect:
e.g. col2: "timestamp" (unix formatted), col3: "size1" uint32, col4: "length" 4 byte float, .... etc.

All these columns contains NULL when I start.

Now I put down a thesis: byte 8:12 from the blob in "data" is a 4 byte int and decodes to "size1" and so for.
To evaluate my thesis I want to fill in col3/"size1" with extraction from the blob in "data".

So what I would need now is a SQL (mariadb) UPDATE which extracts the bytes from the blob and stores it in "col3".
One column is called "pulse_max". With this it works nice, because I need only 1 byte:

**UPDATE dictionary2
SET pulse_max=ascii(SUBSTRING(data, 147, 1));**

But how can I "convert"/unpack" larger (2, 4 byte etc.) parts of the blob to int, uint, double, unixtimestamp, .... etc.?
Things like these fail: (column "tracklenght" is a 4 byte uint.)

**UPDATE dictionary2 SET tracklength= binary(SUBSTRING(data, 113, 4));**

==> Warning: #1366 Falscher integer-Wert: '\x94L\xFEE' für Feld 'tracklength' in Zeile 1

**UPDATE dictionary2                                                                                                                                                                                                         SET duration_time=CONV(REVERSE(HEX(substring(data,109,4))),16,10);**

==> This gives nonsense (my source data is little endian). Maybe the 4 bytes are ordered wrong?

I KNOW I could do all this with C/perl/python/etc. (htonl, unpack etc.) - however these programs do not allow me to store many datasamples and allow a mass evaluation of my thesis.

Of course I can use python/perl mariadb connectors. However I would like to do it directly in SQL and STORE the routines in the database.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had a few posts to it. I deleted them all, because now I have a halfway nice solution. I expected an integrated "function" by SQL/mariadb. That was not the case so I wrote my own. There you are, if you are looking for a similar solution:

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS unpackf4;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION unpackf4(b BLOB(4))
RETURNS FLOAT  DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE f_value FLOAT;
DECLARE binstr CHAR(32);
SET binstr =  LPAD(CONV(HEX(CAST(reverse(b) AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET
utf8)),16,2),32,'0');
SET f_value =
POW(-1,CONV(SUBSTRING( binstr  , 1, 1),2,10))*
POW( 2,CONV(SUBSTRING( binstr  , 2, 8),2,10)-127)*
(1+    CONV(SUBSTRING( binstr  , 10,23),2,10)/POW(2,23));
RETURN f_value;
END; //
DELIMITER ;

With this function one can simply "convert/unpack" a blob column to float32 (double64 will be analogous):

UPDATE dictionary2 SET tracklength      = unpackf4(substring(data,113,4));

While obviously DATA is a blob column and tracklenght a float column.